# Explanation for Level difference of Draenor and Outland?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In WoW we know that Outland's mobs are between level 60-70 as fitting with the Burning Crusade expansion. In WoD the mobs are level 90-100, WoD is also based 30 years prior to the events of BC.

Is there an explanation in the lore for the mobs suddenly dropping 30 levels in strength during this time period?

One could assume that it was because of the Burning Legion coming along and messing up everyone's day, but is there an official explanation for why the mobs get weaker over that 30 year period?

Comment: Given that Blizzard doesn't even explain why zones right next to each other have level differences...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's just a gameplay concession. The comparative levels and stats of monsters have always been largely lore-independent, and WoD is no exception.

Dating all the way back to the original launch of the game, lore-equivalent monsters in neighboring zones (often within eyesight of each other!) can have a level disparity of 40 levels, or even more. Naturally, there's no lore-based reason for this, it's just necessary to provide a progression path and to provide content tuned to different level ranges as the player levels up their character.

Similarly, a five-person [dungeon boss](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=77734/terongor) is not canonically stronger than an [Old God](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=15589/eye-of-cthun), but based on raw stats, that would appear to be the case.

Comment: My personal, lore-based explanation is that level is a function of time, more than power. If C'thun is 30-some levels below Teron'gor, it's not because Teron'gor is that much stronger, but because we as adventurers dealt with the threat C'thun posed long before Teron'gor assaulted Auchindoun (from our point of view). Similarly, if Zalazane was only level 10, it's because he was the first big threat new Trolls and Orcs encountered before heading into the world. The Cataclysm revamp is, to the best of my knowledge, the only case where lower-level content canonically comes after higher levels